# split string based on text qualifier regex java

Tags: java, regex, split

I want to split a string based on text qualifier for example

```
"1","10411721","MikeTison","08/11/2009","21/11/2009","2800.00","002934538","051","New York","10411720-002",".\Images\b.jpg",".\RTF\b.rtf"
```

Qualifer=`"`
Spliter = `,`

I want to split string based on Spliter `,` but if Spliter  comes inside qualifier `"` than ignore it and return string including Spliter .

Regular expression i am using is `(?:|,)(\"(?:[^\"]+|\"\")*\"|[^,]*)`

but this regular expression only returns commas,please help me in this perspective as i am new to regular expressions

please note that if we have newline characters in string ie `\r\n` than it should ignore newline character

```
"1","10411","Muis","a","21/11/2009","2800.06","0029683778","03005136851","Awan","10411720-001",".\Images\a.jpg",".\RTF\a.rtf"
"2","08/10/2009","07:32","Call","On-Net","030092343242342376543","Monk","00:00","1.500","0.000","10.000","0.200"
"2","08/10/2009","02:50","Call","Off-Net","030092343242342376543","Une","08:00","1.500","2.000","20.000","3.500"
"2","09/10/2009","03:55","SMS","On-Net","030092343242342376543","Mink","00:00","1.500","0.000","5.000","100.500"
"2","09/10/2009","12:30","Call","Off-Net","030092343242342376543","Zog","01:01","3.500","3.000","70.000","6.500"
"2","09/10/2009","09:11","Call","On-Net","030092343242342376543","Monk","02:30","2.00","2.000","90.000","4.000"
```

Comment: What is your expected output for the given input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably easiest solution is not searching for place to `split`, but `find`ing elements which you want to return. In your case these elements

- starts `"`
- ends with `"`
- have no `"` inside.

So you try with something like

```
String data = "\"1\",\"10411721\",\"MikeTison\",\"08/11/2009\",\"21/11/2009\",\"2800.00\",\"002934538\",\"051\",\"New York\",\"10411720-002\",\".\\Images\\b.jpg\",\".\\RTF\\b.rtf\"";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]+)\"");
Matcher m = p.matcher(data);
while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Output:

```
1
10411721
MikeTison
08/11/2009
21/11/2009
2800.00
002934538
051
New York
10411720-002
.\Images\b.jpg
.\RTF\b.rtf
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first and the last character of the whole string. Then split with ","

```
String test = "\"1\",\"10411721\",\"MikeTison\",\"08/11/2009\",\"21/11/2009\",\"2800.00\",\"002934538\",\"051\",\"New York\",\"10411720-002\",\".\\Images\\b.jpg\",\".\\RTF\\b.rtf\"";

if (test.length() > 0)
  test = test.substring(1, test.length()-1);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test.split("\",\"")));
```

Comment: i don't want to remove first and last character from string because with this   qualifier disturbs i want solution with regular expression

Comment: The code I gave above splits your example just fine. What is the problem?

Comment: And the code works just fine with any qualifier splitter combination

Comment: it works fine with single line string but if we have \r\n (new line character) in string than it doesn't work fine @Nuri Tasdemir

Comment: If new line character is inside a qualified string, it is no problem. On the other hand if the new line character is outside of qualified strings, then this is not the same question you asked above.

Answer (score 0):

You can split using this regex:

```
String[] arr = input.split( "(?=(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$),+" );
```

This regex will split on commas if those are outside double quotes by using a lookahead to make sure there are even number of quotes after a comma.

Comment: @anubhave thanks for reply but the expression you provided not works in the case if we have new line characters \r\n in the string ,it will combine last word inside qualifer and first word after new line characters

Comment: Well this worked on your given input. You should edit the question and show some code where it is not working then I can definitely tweak it further.

Answer (score 0):

This works even if you have new line character..try it out

```
    String str="\"1\",\"10411721\",\"MikeTison\",\"08/11/2009\",\"21/11/2009\",\"2800.00\",\"002934538\",\"051\",\"New York\",\"10411720-002\",\".\\Images\\b.jpg\",\".\\RTF\\b.rtf\"";
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)")));
```